# Different sized vectors in word2vec

Tags: python, vector, word2vec

I am trying to generate three different sized output vectors namely 25d, 50d and 75d. I am trying to do so by training the same dataset using the word2vec model. I am not sure how I can get three vectors of different sizes using the same training dataset. Can someone please help me get started on this? I am very new to machine learning and word2vec. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run the code for one model three times, each time supplying a different `vector_size` parameter to the model initialization.